# MVC Partial View Postback calling wrong method

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following partial view with an Html.FormBegin helper method;

```
@if (Session["UserSpecific"]!=null) //(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @* @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })*@

            <input type="button" class="menu-button nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-target=".customer-list" data-toggle="collapse" />

            <div class="customer-list-container">
                <div class="customer-list collapse">
                    <ul>
                        @{
                            string[] array = { "Steel Company", "Recycling Company", "Other Company", "Random Name Here" };   
                        }

                        @foreach (string name in array)
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(name, "", "", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "customer-link" })</li><hr/>
                        }

                        <li><input type="submit" /></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</div><div class="col-xs-6"><!--<input type="submit" value="Log Off"/>-><!--<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></div><div class="clearfix">--></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I click on the Submit button, instead of logging out, it runs through the LogIn method again, and modifies the URL to read:

```
Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogOff
```

I don't get why it is running through the LogIn method again, since the Html.BeginForm method specifies that it will use the LogOff method in the Account controller.

The Login method that gets called:

```
        // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

The LogOff method that should be called:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        //AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        Session.Remove("UserSpecific");
        Session["UserSpecific"] = null;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Does either your `HomeController`, or the just the `Index` action method on your `HomeController` have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

Comment: The Index action method has been marked with AllowAnonymous, but the Login action method was still being hit when I put a break in my code, rather than the LogOff action method(which should be getting called per the Html.BeginForm method)

Comment: Is this partial being rendered inside `<form>` tags in the main view? (nested forms are invalid and not supported)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Index` action method on your `HomeController` is not marked with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, which means when the browser attempts to access it after being logged out it gets redirected to the login page again because you're trying to access a page that is accessible only to authenticated users.

Try adding `[AllowAnonymous]`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [AllowAnonymous] // <-- add this
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: That did not help, the LogOff() method in the AccountController.cs is still not being hit when I put a breakpoint in it, but the Login marked with [AllowAnonymous] still is being hit.

Comment: Is it because your form is configured as `FormMethod.Post`, but you've commented out the `[HttpPost]` attribute out on your `LogOff` action method?

Comment: Whoops, let me fix that. I noticed it after I posted and changed it in my code, but forgot to change it here

Comment: Have you tried using the browser dev tools Net tab to see if an error is being returned from the request to `/Account/LogOff`?

Comment: I am not familiar with those tools, so I'll look into those. However, when I browse to /Account/LogOff, it returns an error that the view does not exist - which it doesn't. My understanding was that the BeginForm method would call whatever action method it was provided with when the corresponding <input> button was clicked. Is this wrong?

Comment: Also, try commenting out the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute from the `LogOff` action method... see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised something interesting, I was facing the same problem with my MVC area calling the index method in the account controller instead of calling the logoff method.
I realised the problem was with a defective routing done in the admin area of the application.
Try testing that to see if you're able to correct it.